# WordPress featured image not showing when sharing via social platform like whatapp

Tags: wordpress

I have checked the HTML source code of the page, and the 'og:image' meta property exists. However, the WordPress featured image is not showing. Can you help me?

PHP Version: 7.4
Wordpress Version: 6.3.2
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBDVK.png)

I have checked the theme and plugin, but I have not found the actual problem.